# display first 25 records, then with every click append another 25 records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I currently have kaminari pagination set up. However, a new spec has come down to instead of paginate records, append another page to the existing record set with every click of a button. I just want to make sure I approach this the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event listener to the record set using jQuery.

When there is a click send an AJAX request to the server to retrieve the next 25 results.

Use jQuery to append that to the end of the existing div.